# Proposta de novo site: "Portuguese language"

Tags: debate, status-pronto

Há uma proposta para um novo **site** na rede StackExchange, "[Portuguese Language](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language)", para questões e discussões sobre a língua portuguesa. Por tabela, também poderá ser usado para perguntas sobre como traduzir palavras e frases de português para inglês.

O [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) (somente em inglês) já está bastante ativo, e o [Spanish Language](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/) e o [Russian Language](https://russian.stackexchange.com/) estão na fase beta.

<strike>Caso estejam interessados, [votem em algumas perguntas](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language) que têm menos de 10 votos, para nos ajudar a chegar à próxima fase!</strike>

---

## Fase de commit

Na fase de *commit*, que é [a fase aonde estamos agora](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language), algo que você pode fazer é convidar os seus amigos a participar, especialmente aqueles que você sabe que vão contribuir de forma significativa (na verdade, você também pode fazer isso na fase de definição). Vale também compartilhar o link no facebook, no twitter, no chat ou qualquer coisa assim.

Para a fase de *commit* terminar com sucesso, são necessários pelo menos 200 usuários "commitados" no total sendo pelo menos 100 deles experientes. Há ainda [um requisito complexo referente a atividade atual de cada um destes usuários](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53733/176034), mas colocando de uma forma simples, [visitar a proposta com frequência na Area 51 faz com que você seja considerado ativo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97362/176034).

[Fonte Victor Stafusa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2487/7210)

Comment: Acho que o Portuguese Language devia se chamar Pascoale (entendedores entenderão)

Comment: Tô tentando votar lá mas não deixa. Diz que eu preciso me registrar. Mas eu já estou registrado. Vou abrir uma pergunta no metão :\

Comment: @Renan a barra do topo da página apareceu após entrar com a sua conta na **Area 51**? Aliás, meu nome de usuário, por algum motivo, não aparece aqui.

Comment: Aparece sim. Mesmo assim ainda pede para eu registrar para fazer qualquer coisa.

Comment: Estranho. Use o "modo privado" do seu navegador para ver se continua assim (pode ser um problema com os cookies).

Comment: Essa proposta é diferente de uma outra com o mesmo nome que tinha algum tempo atrás? Lembro de ter feito uma ou duas perguntas nela, mas não as encontro em nenhum lugar...

Comment: @mgibsonbr não sei dizer.

Comment: @mgibsonbr é outra sim, aquela expirou o prazo. Vamos ver se desta vez vai.

Comment: Votei pra reabrir por estar ligada com o nossos interesses pela questão de termos uma variedade maior de sites da SE em nossa língua. Abre-se exceção pra tanta coisa no SOpt, mesmo contra a vontade da comunidade. Creio que aqui cabe o bom senso de uma exceção.

Comment: @Bacco se calhar convinha modificar a pergunta, uma vez que a fase de *define* já lá vai a muito, agora está em fase de *commit*...

Answer (score 12):

## Começou o beta privado

Editado:

## E agora começou o beta público

## :D

Comment: \o/ Parabéns a todos que participaram do beta privado!!

Answer (score 6):

Parece que finalmente está *committed* a proposta [Portuguese Language](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language)  :)

EN

> A successful site needs people to commit to use it. This proposal is
>   100% complete. Committed users will be invited to the private beta
>   soon.

PT

> Um site bem sucedido precisa de pessoas para comprometerem-se a usá-lo.
>   Esta proposta está 100% concluída. Usuários que se comprometeram serão
>   convidados para o beta privado em breve.

Comment: Só nos resta esperar o *"em breve"*.

Comment: **Atenção senhores passageiros para o beta privado do Portuguese Language: Última chamada para o commit imediato na proposta da Area 51.**

Comment: @VictorStafusa ahahahahahahahahahah

Comment: Vamos cruzar os dedos para não sermos surpreendidos novamente com um *#closed*.