# Super User em Português - Já era no Area 51

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, status-recusado, superuser

A proposta foi fechada unilateralmente pela SE. (Links relevantes: [(1)](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20076/49940), [(2)](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2543/super-user-em-portugu%c3%aas-porque-o-projeto-foi-fechado), [(3)](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2546/devemos-aceitar-perguntas-do-supt)). Não vou nem perder meu tempo discutindo. A gente já sabe que eles fazem o que acham melhor mesmo que não faça nenhum sentido. Eles mataram antes que a proposta tivesse a chance de se mostrar viável, coisa que eu sei que aconteceria, poderia levar algum tempo, eu tinha estratégias para resolver o problema que eles alegam, mas mais uma vez eles tomaram uma decisão unilateral, autoritária, sem possibilidade de discussão. Este tipo de coisa vai cansando.

Você ainda pode se cadastrar na proposta [Portuguese Language](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language?referrer=TlbO3u2TSKEUwGHuhaux3w2).

---

Participe da criação do novo site [Super User em Português](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/84282/super-user-em-portugues?referrer=iQLJgvwKWiaSZMVw5WkVIw2).

Faça o **Commit!** na proposta. Você deverá colocar seu nome completo e seu e-mail se ainda não estiver cadastrado no Area51 (não esqueça de verificar seu e-mail e confirmar seu cadastro, isto é muito importante para finalizar o cadastro).

[image: SUpt]

## A parte mais importante

Você também pode contribuir com a criação do novo *site* indicando novos usuários. Compartilhe o *link* nas redes sociais e seu *blog*. Convide seus amigos e parentes. Colegas de trabalho ou de escola (alunos e professores), clientes e outros conhecidos. Não se esqueça que qualquer pessoa pode ser um beneficiário deste novo *site*. Ele não é só para profissionais. A sua mãe pode usá-lo. Se puder, ajude a pessoa que está indicando a completar todo o processo do cadastro (que é simples mas por estar em inglês algumas pessoas poderão se confundir).

Indicar novos usuários dá pontos e medalha no Area51.

Se puder, vote [nesse *post* no meta do Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/q/9166/20555) em inglês.

Visite a proposta de vez em quando para reativar sua participação (uma vez por mês já seria legal, embora eu espero que nem demore mais que um mês para concluir o processo).

Você pode se interessar também pela proposta [Portuguese Language](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language?referrer=TlbO3u2TSKEUwGHuhaux3w2).

Se tiver dúvidas, poste aqui.

Vou deixar abaixo o texto inicial se você tiver paciência de ler.

---

## TL; DR

- Siga a nova proposta do [Super User em Português](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/84282/super-user-em-portugues?tab=votes) (Clique em **Follow It!** e não esqueça de confirmar seu e-mail quando a mensagem for enviada, caso você seja novo na [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/))
- **Vote nas 5 perguntas** que acha que deveriam fazer parte do novo *site*. Esta é a parte mais importante (veja as dicas dadas abaixo na resposta do Victor)
- Convide pessoas que você conhece para fazer o mesmo

[image: SUpt]

Se você já votou considere trocar seu voto se ele está em perguntas exemplo com mais de 10 votos ou se está em uma pergunta com apenas 1 voto (há perguntas de mais com votos, só precisamos de 40).

## O SOpt é um sucesso

Mais cedo ou mais tarde precisaríamos de outros sites em português. Não sei quanto a SE está interessada em fazer outros. Já tivemos informações que isto não vai acontecer tão fácil.

Temos a proposta [Portuguese Language](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language) em fase final de seleção. Não sei se ela pode ser considerada em português, não sei se a língua oficial dela seria o português e se a UI seria traduzida. É uma coisa p/ a SE decidir. De qualquer forma fica a dica para você fazer o *commit* lá. Me parece ser útil para todos que usam o português me que seu interesse direto não seja tão grande.

O ideal é não ter muitas propostas, na verdade provavelmente não podemos abrir novas sem que as anteriores sejam efetivadas. Mas podemos considerar o SOpt efetivado. Não temos a graduação formal mas podemos nos considerar graduados. Então é hora da criação de mais uma proposta de *site* em português.

Sempre vimos e mais recentemente estamos vendo alguma demanda extra por perguntas de uso de softwares. Isto nunca foi considerado adequado para o SOpt mas por não ter outro lugar para perguntar em alguns casos acabavam sendo aceitas perguntas *off-topic*.

## O SOpt não é suficiente

Está na hora disto mudar. Bom, a hora exata a gente não sabe. A SE fará no tempo dela e se ela achar que deve. É um direito dela decidir se o *site* será criado ou não.

Se você não conhece o processo, visite o [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). Lá tem propostas de *sites* que passam por uma fase de definição onde 40 perguntas exemplo com uma votação de no mínimo 10 votos são usados pela SE para ajudar entender a proposta. Ela não precisa seguir estritamente o que a definição sugeriu mas é um bom indicador.

Quando atingir a votação destas perguntas e um número de seguidores passa-se para a fase de *commit* onde 200 usuários precisam dizer que querem participar do *site* (o cálculo é um pouco mais complicado). Depois disto a SE demora de alguns dias há alguns anos (foi o caso do SOpt) para criar o *site* que no futuro poderá ser graduado ou não.

Alguém tem alguma dúvida que um *site* em português sobre TI como um todo seria um enorme sucesso? Possivelmente mais que o SOpt. E seria mais útil ainda que o SOpt. Seria um *site* que poucos usuários poderia se beneficiar sem a versão em português.

## Vamos criar um novo *site*

Então está criada a proposta para o [**Super User em português**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/84282/super-user-em-portugues).

## Como ajudar?

Vamos todos ajudar definir o que ele é. A minha visão dele é que seja um *site* mais amplo e mais agregador que o Super User original que segregou algumas tecnologias por diversas razões. Sem entrar no mérito de isto ter sido bom ou ruim. Inicialmente não podemos segregar muita coisa. Minha visão é que qualquer assunto de TI que são seja diretamente ligado ao desenvolvimento de software cabe no SUpt.

Para ajudar você deve criar perguntas exemplo. Precisamos de pelo menos 40, provavelmente mais. Seria bom ter exemplos ruins para as pessoas fecharem e darem uma boa indicação do que não pode. Precisamos de algumas dezenas com **boa diversidade de tópicos** mas não muitas dezenas. **Não faz sentido ter perguntas muito parecidas** que na verdade representam o mesmo tópico. Isto não ajuda a definir nada. Se você não consegue ser criativo para criar perguntas que exprimem um tópico novo considere se abster de criar uma pergunta. Nem todo mundo mundo precisa criar perguntas. Todo mundo precisa seguir a proposta e votar positivamente em 5 questões exemplos. Pode negativar quantas quiser. Mas só negative se tiver certeza que a pergunta é muito ruim. Prefira fechar se for pertinente.

Para quem não conhece o processo é bom atentar para que as perguntas exemplo devem ser pensadas para indicar quais tópicos devem ser aceitos. Ou seja, ter duas perguntas do mesmo tópico não ajuda muito a definição. Não que seja proibido. Em alguns casos uma alta incidência do mesmo tópico de pergunta também é um indicador mas pode estar prejudicando a visibilidade de outros tópicos também importantes.

Alguns não vão gostar do que vou dizer. Vote estrategicamente. As perguntas não precisam ter mais que 10 votos. Eu remanejo votos quando vejo que passou disto (lá é permitido fazer isto). Eu acho interessante que você o faça também. Não faz sentido todo mundo votar em algumas poucas perguntas. Principalmente neste caso que é um *site* que a SE tem uma ideia do que deve ser. Não é um assunto desconhecido para ela. Não estou dizendo para você votar em coisas que você não acha que estar no *site*, claro que não, apenas para distribuir melhor os votos em perguntas úteis, na sua opinião. Isto não prejudica em nada a definição da proposta. Além do que a SE fará do jeito que ela achar melhor independente do que for votado lá. Isto sempre acontece. Se você acha que não deve votar estrategicamente é só não fazer. Não há benefício algum nisto mas respeito sua decisão.

Basta postar perguntas exemplo e votar? Não. Você também pode **ajudar recomendando a proposta para outras pessoas**. Virtualmente qualquer pessoa que você conheça pode se beneficiar deste novo *site* de Q&A. Elas também podem ajudar de todas as formas, mas mesmo que apenas sigam a proposta já ajuda. Quanto mais rápido passarmos para a fase de *commit* e atingirmos os 200 usuários, mais fácil convencemos a SE que o *site* é importante. Se é que ela já não sabe disto.

## [Super User em Português](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/84282/super-user-em-portugues)

Particularmente não é um *site* que eu vou participar muito mas certamente irei me beneficiar dele. Acho que todos argumentos para a criação do SOpt se aplicam de forma mais forte para o SUpt. A SE deveria fazê-lo pelo menos para ver o que acontece.

Eu já sugeri lá na página de discussão da proposta no Area 51 algumas perguntas que podem ser feitas. Estas perguntas forma retiradas dos *sites* existentes.

Vejo este novo *site* como oportunidade excelente para a SE montar um *site* que fique claro desde o primeiro dia para todos os envolvidos que é para aceitar quase tudo o que se queira perguntar e que a qualidade não precisa seguir os mesmo padrões do que os outros *sites* da rede seguem. O público alvo deste *site* realmente pede um *site* mais livre e menos rígido que *sites* estritamente profissionais como deveria ser o caso do SOpt. Inclusive se lá for estabelecido que listas de *links* são bons, fica mais fácil eliminar daqui, afinal listas de *links* são de interesse de usuários em geral mesmo que esses *links* sejam para conteúdo de interesse de programadores. Afinal os programadores serão usuários desses *links*.

Acho que o primeiro *post* do meta do SUpt será

## Aqui NÃO É o superuser.com

:D E é bom que todos saibam disto antes mesmo deles se comprometerem com o *site*.

## Teremos SUpt

[oba, o @Gabe deu o SUpt como certo! \o/](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34682354#34682354) (leia a conversa e veja o contexto antes de tirar conclusões).

## Conclusão final

Esquece, não terá mais nenhum site internacional a não ser que mude completamente a administração atual e enxerguem de forma diferente. E nem acho ruim, se eles não investirem nisso é melhor não ter mesmo. Já questiono até o SOpt que não tem mais o diferencial que tinha antes.

Comment: Bora lá a isso! Acho que devias explicar melhor qual é o *on-topic* do SUpt.

Comment: Lá nele próprio tem uma explicação (em inglês). Mas na verdade eu não posso explicar muito. Nós é que vamos definir o que é *on-topic*. Será um trabalho colaborativo. Eu posso influenciar mas não definir sozinho. Você pode pode ajudar, pode colocar sua visão do que ele deveria ser. Além de postar perguntas exemplos e votar lá, claro.

Comment: Sem duvida será muito útil também, já estou seguindo!

Comment: Nossa! A proposta tem pouco mais de 6 horas de vida e já tem 34 questões de exemplo (1 fechada)! Nunca vi isso acontecer na Area 51. :O

Comment: O número de perguntas está bom até demais mas a diversidade delas me preocupa um pouco. Boa parte delas no fundo são sobre a mesma coisa. Talvez seja porque as pessoas não querem que o SUpt seja diferente do SUen mas provavelmente seria um erro ser restritivo. Mesmo que fosse uma boa ideia, o que eu não acha que seja, a SE dificilmente aceitaria. Ou pode ser apenas que o pessoal não está criativo o suficiente para postar perguntas que mostrem a diversidade pretendida. Quem for postar perguntas, pense antes se vai colocar algo original que ajudará mais.

Comment: Eu esperava mais usuários seguindo e mais votos nas perguntas. Tem usuários que já viram que tem a proposta mas nem se deram conta que é para participar :) Certamente será útil para eles de uma forma ou de outra. Eu até acho que ainda tem poucas pessoas que viram. Minha intenção não era criar a proposta já (praticamente no carnaval) mas foi necessário. Mas as que viram poderiam ter se interessado mais. Duvido o programador que não precisará daquele site hora ou outra.

Comment: É legal rever certos posts que duvidavam deste *site* http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/19827/19348 e http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/19829/19348

Comment: EU já tinha levantado a bandeira de um superuser em pt ano passado na area51, mas houve uma reviravolta e não pude dedicar o tempo suficente pra proposta.. mas já votei e estou seguindo a sua proposta bigown!

Comment: @bigown muito obrigado por me mostrar a proposta, eu estou bem inativo pelas bandas de cá, mas sempre quis uma proposta para uma versão pt do SuperUser, estarei acompanhando, e evangelizando a sua aprovação de agora em diante. :D

Comment: @bigown Tinha esquecido do e-mail. Agora estou lá!

Comment: Agora só falta o Arqade em português.

Comment: @bigown tenho estado ausente...umas férias...merecidas.... mas já está.. vamos em frente. força.

Comment: Closed? Porque? Não entendi...

Comment: Só sei que no que depender de mim, continuam sendo off topic as questões que deveriam ser postas no SUpt, então é problema da SE arranjar um lugar pra elas, e não nosso

Comment: @Earendul Eu nem entro aí depois de ter visto um monte de papo furado, argumentos vazios e até censura, baseada em convicções pessoais aliadas a poderes na mão errada. Eventualmente espio algum permalink quando vejo em algum lugar, mas prefiriria coisas como o chat que o JorgeB indicou (apesar de andar vazio) por ser "extraoficial". [irc.freenode.net #SOptMesaDeBar](https://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=SOPtMesaDeBar)

Comment: Proponho novo título: "Super User em Português - Já _era_ no Area 51" :)

Comment: Só registrando que existe uma cópia do post que foi deletado [.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150418235137/http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/20076/supt-can-be-awesome-but-in-a-more-distant-future)

Comment: Acredito que se for possivel, o @gabe vai acabar deletando todo o histórico do chat, e jogar a culpa no estagiário que derramou o cafe no data center :P

Comment: @bigown não devia mudar para status-aceite?

Comment: @JorgeB.melhor não, não é uma certeza mesmo.

Comment: Cadê ? .........

Answer (score 23):

## Fase de commit

Na fase de *commit*, que é [a fase aonde estamos agora](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/84282?phase=commitment), algo que você pode fazer é convidar os seus amigos a participar, especialmente aqueles que você sabe que vão contribuir de forma significativa (na verdade, você também pode fazer isso na fase de definição). Vale também compartilhar o link no facebook, no twitter, no chat ou qualquer coisa assim. Aliás, você também poderia fazer isso agora com [a comunidade de língua portuguesa](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language), que também está na fase de *commit*.

Para a fase de *commit* terminar com sucesso, são necessários pelo menos 200 usuários "commitados" no total sendo pelo menos 100 deles experientes. Há ainda [um requisito complexo referente a atividade atual de cada um destes usuários](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53733/176034), mas colocando de uma forma simples, [visitar a proposta com frequência na Area 51 faz com que você seja considerado ativo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97362/176034).

## Fase de definição

**Já passamos por esta fase**. :) Mas vou manter o texto aqui por referência histórica e também porque ele também pode ser aplicado para outras propostas na Area 51:

Para agilizar o processo na fase de definição da Area 51, é importante que os usuários ajam de forma estratégica. Vou detalhar melhor a forma estratégica delineada pelo bigown:

Na fase de definição, precisamos de 40 perguntas com 10 ou mais votos. Entretanto, é importante notar-se que elas são contadas na base do tudo ou nada. Uma pergunta com 1000 votos a favor tem o mesmo peso que uma pergunta com 10 votos a favor. Uma pergunta com 9 votos a favor tem o mesmo peso que uma pergunta sem nenhum voto ou mesmo com votação negativa. E uma vez que cada usuário só pode votar a favor de cinco perguntas, então isso significa que os seus votos devem ser usados com sabedoria. Portanto:

- Votar em perguntas que já chegaram a 10 votos é despediçar o seu voto aonde ele não é mais necessário, é chover no molhado. Não vote em perguntas que já atingiram 10 votos. Se você votou em alguma pergunta, e depois viu que ela passou de 10 votos, remova o seu voto e utilize-o em outra pergunta.
- Votar em perguntas que nunca atingirão 10 votos também é despediçar o seu voto. Se você votou em alguma pergunta e posteriormente viu que ela não vai atingir 10 votos, retire o seu voto e coloque-o em outra questão com melhores chances.
- Idealmente, as pessoas deveriam ter um comportamento tal que não deixassem que mais de 40 perguntas não-fechadas recebessem votos positivos. Espalhar os votos em um número de perguntas maior do que 40 também é um desperdício, pois isso significa que um número ainda maior de votos serão necessários já que alguns deles estarão em perguntas que nunca receberão os 10 votos necessários. É claro que você não pode controlar as ações dos outros usuários, mas tente fazer a sua parte ao votar de uma forma que os votos não acabem sendo espalhados em perguntas demais.
- Votar a favor de questões fechadas é desperdiçar o seu voto. Se você votou em uma questão e ela posteriormente foi fechada, retire o seu voto e coloque-o em uma outra questão.
- Votar contra uma questão é perigoso, e pense muito bem antes de fazer isso. O motivo é que neste caso você estará desperdiçando o voto de alguma outra pessoa caso a pergunta tenha um número de votos positivo. Como o bigown já disse, se a pergunta for ruim, o melhor é simplesmente fechá-la.
- Não usar todos os seus cinco votos a favor também não contribui, obviamente.

Além disso, temos um pequeno detalhe matemático. Na fase de definição, como o bigown já explicou, oficialmente precisamos de 60 seguidores e 40 perguntas não fechadas com 10 ou mais votos. E cada seguidor só pode dar 5 votos a favor. Entretanto:

> 40 perguntas * 10 votos / 5 votos por pessoa = 80 pessoas.

Ou seja, na verdade e na prática precisamos de 80 pessoas **no mínimo**. E isso em uma situação utópica aonde há exatamente 40 perguntas com votos positivos, todas elas com exatamente 10 votos cada, sem nenhum voto ser desperdiçado e com todos os usuários usando todos os votos que têm direito. Na prática, como o mundo não é tão perfeito assim, vamos precisar de pelo menos uns 150 seguidores. Ok, é verdade que não-seguidores também podem votar e por causa disso, em teoria, é possível passar-se a fase de definição com apenas 60 seguidores, mas há pouco sentido em votar a favor sem seguir e tal atitude é bastante incomum.

E para esclarecer alguns pontos levantados em comentários, se for necessário remanejar votos, não há limite de tempo para fazê-lo. Portanto, se você votou a favor de alguma pergunta e então um mês depois (supondo que a fase de *commit* ainda não tenha começado), ao voltar à proposta viu que por algum dos motivos acima seria bom remanejar o voto, você pode fazê-lo sem nenhum problema. A única razão que pode existir para segurar um voto em alguma proposta é se não houver nenhuma pergunta aonde colocá-lo, e este definitivamente não é o nosso caso, pois em apenas um dia já conseguimos um número suficiente de perguntas e até temos sobrando! Logo, no Super User em português, não há motivo para segurar votos.

Ah sim, e se você precisar retirar um voto a favor (ou contra) é fácil: Assim como para votar basta clicar na setinha, para retirar o voto é só clicar na mesma setinha novamente.

E um outro detalhezinho: Quando você começa a seguir a proposta sendo um usuário novo da Area 51, [você só será contado como um seguidor se tiver recebido e respondido adequadamente um e-mail de verificação](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238808/176034). Se você já é um usuário antigo de lá que já teve o seu e-mail verificado no passado, isso não será necessário.

Comment: Excelente explicação. Eu quis ser mais "politicamente correto" mas você tem toda razão. Mesmo que você que está lendo isto não queira seguir a proposta vote nas perguntas que acha que seriam boas para o *site*. E porque você não tem interesse nesta proposta? Qualquer usuário de computadores deveriam estar nela já! E isto pode lhe dar a medalha de ouro mais fácil da sua vida, se lhe interessar por isto. Ajude a proposta prosperar mesmo que não tenha tanto interesse assim. Duvido que não vai dar uma passadinha lá e aproveitar alguma coisa.

Comment: Para defender a posição do Victor se alguém achar que isto é manipulação eu digo que na prática a SE vai criar o *site* se ela quiser e como ela quiser. Além de outros *sites*, o SOpt é prova que o Area 51 é apenas uma pesquisa de mercado. Neste caso esta votação é na verdade formalidade. A SE sabe que este *site* é viável e o que deve ter nele. Mesmo que ainda não saiba ela vai discutir isto e decidir o que é melhor para nós. Ela já deixou claro que ela é que sabe disto. Não importa o que votemos o *site* sairá de acordo com a vontade e interesses dela. E isto não é necessariamente ruim.

Comment: Faça o que quiser, pense como quiser mas ajude a proposta prosperar rápido mas mostrar para a SE que realmente queremos o *site*. Praticamente não precisamos mais de perguntas precisamos de seguidores e votos na perguntas. Participe e chame outras pessoas para participar. Mesmo pessoas aqui do SOpt que ainda não perceberam que estão preparando o World Domination do Português :)

Comment: +1 pelas informações extras, estou na Area 51 e não sabia de todos esses detalhes!

Comment: Ah sim, adicionei o link explicando dos detalhes dos requisitos mais complicados da fase de commit: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53733/176034 - http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97362/176034

Comment: Existe algum tempo limite para tirar o voto positivo de uma questão para usar em outra?

Comment: @AndréRibeiro Não, não existe.

Comment: Este é outro detalhe importante, Gaste todos os 5 votos logo para ajudar subir na listagem de progresso e de *sites* quentes. Depois você vai mudando o voto conforme a necessidade. Agiliza o progresso e aumenta a atividade quente quando for mudar o voto. Não tem razão para segurar voto.

Comment: Para tentar dar uma referência como o processo está caducando, é provável que num futuro o A51 nem exista mais, pelo menos não na forma atual. http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/5089/next-generation-of-area-51#comment28465_5102

Comment: Já tem casos para fazer remanejamento.

Comment: O que acontece se eu apagar um pergunta minha com upvote? É que ela tem um downvote.

Comment: @JorgeB. Ela é apagada, só isto. Aí é claro que poderá criar outra no lugar se já tinha criado 5.

Comment: @bigown mas e os 2 votos que tenho nela?

Comment: @JorgeB. remove também :) Não terá mais a pergunta onde os votos foram dados. Provavelmente é melhor deixar.

Comment: Já tem mais de 40 perguntas com votos. Se alguém votou em alguma que está só com um voto, seria bom trocar o voto para algo que já contenha voto. E já tem pergunta com mais de 10 votos também.

Comment: Hoje alguns usuários começaram a votar em perguntas com 10 de reputação, praticamente estão jogando o voto fora. Alguma forma de incentivá-los a retirar o voto e atribui-lo a uma pergunta em que os votos estão < 10? Nem todo mundo lê o Meta.

Comment: @renan Acho que dá para postar um comentário com um link para cá.