# Super User em Português - Por que o projeto foi fechado?

Tags: debate

Hoje descobri que havia um projeto em andamento para criar um Super User em português. Pensei "ótimo, estamos precisando mesmo". Mas ao chegar na [página do projeto](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/84282/super-user-em-portugues) vi que o projeto foi fechado como não sendo uma proposta viável. Existem mais detalhes sobre o motivo da inviabilidade? Me parecia uma ótima ideia.

Comment: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/20076/supt-can-be-awesome-but-in-a-more-distant-future

Comment: "O Tim deu 2 motivos pro fechamento:
1. O novo site vai dividir a comunidade, e ao invés de 1 site grande forte e saudável, teríamos 2 sites menores, mais fracos e menos saudáveis
2. Internamente não temos condição de dar suporte a 2 sites internacionais na mesma língua" by @Gabe

Comment: Os 2 são refutáveis. 1. a proposta ñ teve tempo p/ mostrar o contrário, já existia alguns experts de fora, alguns q eu conheço bem e q apesar d ter contas no SOpt, ñ participam ativamente pq trabalham c/ infra e adorariam o SUpt. Se bobear o SUpt teria + experts q o SOpt q tem bem poucos. A Se erra muito só olhando números pelados. Números mentem. Eu sei + sobre o perfil dos usuários do q eles. Eles só sabem dos números. Eu estava preparando estratégias p/ resolver o problema q eles alegam. Mas ñ tive tempo. Eles meteram os pés pelas mãos, como já está ficando comum.

Comment: 2. tem CM q cuida de dezenas d sites e são usuários normais muito ativos. Aqui temos um CM dedicado q ñ tem tempo p/ cuidar d 1 site, q nem consegue usar o site. Na verdade ele nem usava os sites da SE antes d se tornar funcionário. O padrão não mudou. Eu entendo q esse começo tenha algumas tarefas extras. Nem esperava q o SUpt fosse criado já, eu sei q precisaria o SOpt ficar + estável. Mas q fosse criado daqui 1, 2 anos, como aconteceu c/ o SOpt. Fechar foi tosco.

Comment: Tem uma discussão rolando no chat mas é perda de tempo. A SE nunca está errada. Ela nunca admite q passou do ponto, q errou. Já vi moderador ser destituído porque vazou informação privada de um usuário. Quando a SE vaza de dezenas seque há um pedido de desculpas formal.

Comment: Detalhe importante é que o ponto 2 já se sabia no dia que a proposta foi lançada. O que não dá para entender porque precisa fechar a proposta. Não cria o site já eu até entendo.

Comment: Mas parece que o sucesso do SOpt está sendo questionado pela SE. Eu acho e estava trabalhando para ter outros experts lá. Talvez tivesse mais que aqui que tem bem poucos. Temos só 1.7 respostas por pergunta que é um índice muito baixo para a rede. Se eu não ajudasse limpar, teríamos só 70% respondidas. Faltam muitos experts aqui. Eles foram embora porque não concordam com a bagunça que está o site. Este é um site de novatos e não de experts. Claramente a SE **aqui** considera que o novato pode tudo e o expert tem q se adaptar a isto. A Se foi criada p/ acontecer o contrário.

Comment: ***NO one*** is questioning the success of SOPT. The manner in which you've arrived at that conclusion is as elusive as it is preposterous. I specifically said that SOPT was doing quite well, and we felt that dividing the community could hurt that success. At what point did I say we were not comfortable with its progress? You are welcome to your speculation but please, don't state it as fact.

Comment: @TimPost you wrote: "we felt that dividing the community could hurt that success (of SOpt)" - do you have data to backup this assumption? SUpt is untested, like SOpt was untested and is now successful. I have the opposite opinion, and many here. Why does your opinion wages more than ours? Who is the panel in SE deciding? Our CM (@Gabe)?

Comment: Não é curioso que a SE adora usar números para mostrar que eles estão certos mesmo que números mentem. Quando um número não mostra o que eles querem, aí esse número não importa. Os dados de quantidade aumentam os de qualidade diminuem. Isto não costuma acontecer em outros sites de sucesso. Mas como sempre a gente tá errado e a SE está certa. O site está tão bem e não devemos ter medo que ele possa ter uma cisão dos muitos especialistas que temos aqui. Então o ponto 1 já foi pro espaço. Essas incoerências cansam. Fatos são aquelas coisas que a SE acredita, o resto é opinião.

Comment: @Sergio The high intersection between committers (especially experts) and the most active users on SOpt is a very big sign the community would be split.

Comment: The people that worked on this Were Me, Gabe, our VP of community growth, Robert (who works almost exclusively with new sites and the area 51 process) and several other seasoned community managers. It was not a decision taken lightly, and was backed up by _a lot_ of experience. We've been doing this a while. We _hoped_  to conclude that we could somehow manage to support it, there just wasn't a way.

Comment: E com toda esta experiência não ajudou nada ter uma ação tão desastrosa. E pra variar ignoram o fato de que a situação poderia mudar se a proposta continuasse aberta. Ignorar o que não interessa é algo que a SE faz cada vez melhor. Em 2 dois anos talvez a proposta tivesse centenas de commits, tivese 70% d usuários de fora, mas como vamos saber. Desde o início eu falava que a SE provavelmente demoraria para criar o site, isso era esperado, o fechamento unilateral não. Mas eles não escutam porque eles precisam se concentrar em falar que escutam.

Comment: @Gabe So what you would expect to do? "People, just tell your friends out there to join the proposal, but don't do it yourselves"? And, as I asked you in chat? From where you suoppose that the 100 users with experience in other SE sites would come from?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Again, the *experts* are "*experts on the subject*", not "*experts on the network*"

Comment: @Gabe Again, I already told that from the 143 commiters, at least 81 declares themselves as expert in the subject. Further the requirement in Area 51 (which we reached 100%) was 100 people with at least 200 points of reputation on other SE's sites.

Comment: @VictorStafusa eles saõ experientes, ele possuem o dom. Eles abem que os experts lá vão parar d usar o SOpt. Eles sabem q outros ñ são suficientes. Eles sabem o perfil dos experts q terão lá mais do que a pessoa que os referenciou, eles sabem que os novos que surgirão não só até chegar nos 100%, mas os que virão depois não serão experts suficientes p/ tornar o site viável, eles sabem q o trabalho q ia fazer não seria suficiente, eles sabem q os experts do SOpt não querem continuar no SOpt, eles sabem q o caos e destruição iria ocorrer, eles sabem como será o futuro.

Comment: Relacionado: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/20083/will-those-proposals-ever-be-launched

Comment: E se não fosse usado o nome "Super User"? Ainda assim a SE implicaria com a proposta?

Comment: Fiquei triste em saber disso. Trabalhei cinco anos com suporte de TI, aprendi muita coisa e sinto que poderia partilhar esse conhecimento. E, além do mais, acredito que pudesse ser talvez maior que o SOPT, mesmo essa informação sendo irrelevante.

Answer (score 15):

## A razão principal

Meu entendimento é que a proposta foi fechada porque a Stack Exchange, empresa que cuida dos sites da rede, não possui no momento atual as capacidades necessárias no que tange aos funcionários e à arquitetura do sistema para dar prosseguimento ao projeto.

## Sobre as outras razões apontadas

Outros motivos foram citados no anúncio, mas quero explicar porque não os considero essenciais.

Ontem no *chat* houve muita discussão circular sobre esses outros motivos. Concordo que é possível argumentar, por exemplo, sobre a questão de dividir a comunidade, mas como foi dito isso não muda a razão principal.

Minha interpretação é que eles tem uma lista de *issues* em relação à proposta. A estrutura que a empresa possui é um *blocker*, o resto são menos graves e até poderiam ser contornados, mas ainda que resolvêssemos todos, o *blocker issue* continuaria lá.

A gente faz esse tipo de coisa o tempo todo sem perceber. Por exemplo, somos convidados para um casamento e já temos um outro compromisso na data. Ao invés de negar dizendo apenas "tenho outro compromisso", muita gente acrescenta coisas como "e também não saberia o que comprar para presente". Note que o segundo motivo é apenas uma "desculpa" acumulada para tentar ficar menos feio, mas tem pouquíssima relevância.

## Sobre a forma como a proposta foi fechada

As principais e mais justas críticas foram com relação à forma como veio o anúncio do fechamento. Todos consideraram algo muito repentino, sendo que a inclinação ao fechamento poderia ter sido sinalizada antes.

Pelo que o @Tim e o @Gabe indicaram ontem no *chat*, eles não conseguiram reagir mais rapidamente ou enxergar uma forma que causasse menos problemas. Por isso o [@Tim pediu desculpas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2545/227):

> For that I apologize

Para todos da comunidade que estão decepcionados, cabe ter paciência e compreensão com a situação para não acabar ferindo a comunidade como um todo.

## Sobre uma possível reabertura da proposta

Muitas argumentaram que a proposta poderia ter sido mantida aberta, porém a equipe da SE apresentou algumas razões para não fazer isso.

Realmente não sei se eles estariam dispostos a reabri-la caso a comunidade interessada desejasse como um todo.

Creio que isso vale uma nova discussão, de preferência quando os ânimos estiverem menos exaltados.

Comment: utluiz acho que a revolta é mesmo essa. Porquê fechar? O único argumento para FECHAR que foi dado pelo @Tim é que a proposta perderia interesse. Não me parece um motivo válido. Até porque existem várias propostas abertas há muito tempo a dependerem de outros fatores. Inclusive, como disseram o SOpt esteve assim por muito tempo.

Comment: Bom resumo. Eu discordo da "não relevância" do segundo ponto principal para o fechamento, de que o SOpt não tem capacidade de suportar o impacto de um outro site com o *mesmo* cerne de comunidade. Nós fechamos **diversas** propostas por esse motivo. O SUpt não foi a primeira, nem a última.

Comment: @JorgeB. O fato de existirem outras propostas abertas por anos, sem um destino definido não torna isso um caminho adequado. "Limbo" nunca deve, e nunca devia, ser uma opção válida para as propostas da A51. Nós estamos avaliando as propostas para poder decidir sobre elas. O SUpt já teve sua decisão, e por isso não deve ser adicionado à pilha de "não sabemos o que vai ser"

Comment: @Gabe Entendo, acho que falhei na analogia. Este é um problema crítico para vocês, mas não bloqueante, pois ainda poderia ser contornado se a comunidade conseguisse mais comprometimento de fora do SOpt.

Comment: @utluiz Difícil. De uma maneira ou de outra, o nível de pessoas comprometidas com a proposta e envolvidas no SOpt era muito grande. A melhor solução pra isso é ter um SOpt maior, coisa que só o tempo pode fazer. Ou uma proposta que envolvesse muito menos gente do SOpt (se fosse, por exemplo, alavancada por usuários lusófonos do SUen)

Comment: @Gabe com esse fechamento vai acontecer o que vocês querem evitar, os utilizadores que SOpt que fizeram o commit vão desmotivar e deixar de responder no SOpt. Nunca iriam deixar o SOpt pelo SUpt até porque uma coisa nada tem a ver com a outra. O povo que fala português se não vai ao SUpt vai a um fórum, como eu.

Comment: @Gabe seja o caminho adequado ou não, é o caminho escolhido por vocês. E é o caminho que (espero que não) vai levar o SOpt ao desastre. Pelo que vi os utilizadores com mais reputação estão todos a virar as costas a SE e consequentemente ao SOpt. Eu desde que aconteceu o episódio das listas já respondo muito menos, agora nem se fala... A este ritmo de imposições da SE o SOpt nem de beta sai...

Comment: Claro que isto é apenas a minha opinião, mas pelo que me parece, é partilhada por uma grande maioria.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to clarify a few things before I get into the reasons that we closed the proposal.

1. We move slower administratively than we'd like to sometimes. This should have happened sooner in the process so that we didn't inadvertently raise anyone's expectations. For that I apologize, the proposal just moved *very* rapidly.
2. We are in no way questioning the success of SOPT ***at all***. I hoped to make that clear in my post, but I'll reiterate it again plainly, just in case.
3. We *want* SUPT, eventually, when we're able to handle it properly and we're certain that  we wouldn't be doing SOPT a disservice by creating it.

Now that I've said that, I'll get into the reasons why I closed it.

***The actual localization component***

We have come *very* far when it comes to the process that we use to bring up a site in a new language. I'm going to be posting more (very soon) on Area 51 about where we stand with it, where we hope to be at the end of the year, and what this means for the growing number of communities that have been waiting for us to reach this point.

The process *still* requires a dedicated community manager per site. We're going to (we hope) get things to the point where we only need one community manager *per language*, which means that SUPT could simply use the translations from SOPT, make some site-specific changes, and be ready to go for a beta.

We're not there yet. I know it sounds like that should be easy, it *should* be easy, and that's why we're working on it.

We don't have the administrative resources to support SOPT now, and probably won't until at least the end of 2015. That *could* change, sometimes during the course of improving and re-inventing how you do stuff, you manage to find small things that make big impacts.

***You're doing very well, but you can't yet support a splinter site***

In order for us to be comfortable going forward, we'd need to be reasonably certain that:

- SUPT would have a committed core of at least 100 or so extremely active users
- That *giving* SUPT this core would not adversely affect SOPT. If you cut participation in /review, bad things can happen, for instance.
- There was a strong enough external demand for SUPT that a new, much larger community would form in a similar manner to SOPT. Maybe not as much, but along the lines.

We think you *will* be there, probably around the time that we're able to run with having one community manager per language instead of per site, but we're not confident enough for this to go through.

***Why shut it down?***

Because once a proposal on Area 51 hits 100%, it starts losing between 5-10% of the interest it had every few weeks that it continues to wait. People find other things to do, they get busy, they get new jobs - the point is we can no longer count on a site having anywhere *near* a sustainable core once it's sat for so long.

We didn't have a clear direction on how localization was going to work beyond knowing that we definitely wanted to do it until *now*, and we don't want yet another proposal to  run out of steam.

***We do want to do this!***

SUPT is unique in that it *already has* a translation that is working its way to being as complete as it will ever get, the one we've done for SOPT. This means more sites in Portuguese could be a much easier target to hit.

We don't want to launch that from a mostly abandoned proposal, any more than we wanted people continuing to work on it with expectations that we couldn't meet. It felt very dishonest to not tell you we couldn't launch it. It also felt misleading to allow people to keep participating in the proposal knowing this.

There was no way to do this without disappointing people, and we really *do not* like disappointing people. We are not saying no, we're simply saying *not yet*, after drawing on the experiences we've had launching over 130 sites, many from the Area 51 process.

This does not mean we're saying no to SUPT. We just can't do it *now*. We should have been ahead of this more than we were so expectations were better managed, and I apologize that we weren't.

---

## Tradução

Antes de continuar a discussão sobre os motivos do fechamento da proposta, gostaria de esclarecer algumas coisas:

1. Algumas vezes nossas decisões demoram mais tempo do que gostaríamos. O fechamento deveria ter ocorrido mais cedo, para evitar que uma expectativa muito grande fosse criada. Pedimos desculpas por não termos agido antes, mas a proposta cresceu *muito* rápido.
2. ***Não estamos questionando o sucesso do SOpt***. Tentei deixar isso bem claro no meu post, mas vale a pena reforçar.
3. Nós *queremos* o SUpt, eventualmente, quando tivermos condições de oferecer suporte da maneira adequada e tivermos certeza de que ele não atrapalharia o SOpt.

Dito isso, vamos aos motivos pelos quais eu fechei a proposta.

***O problema com sites internacionais***

O processo para criar sites internacionais já melhorou *bastante*, comparada ao que era antes. Nos próximos dias vou escrever, na Area 51, sobre o estado atual, como queremos estar até o final do ano e como isso afeta todas as comunidades que estão aguardando alguma resposta nossa.

No momento, *ainda* é necessário que exista um gerente de comunidades dedicado a cada um dos sites. Nosso plano (esperamos) é eventualmente precisar apenas de um gerente *por língua*. Isso significa que o SUpt poderia usar as mesmas traduções de interface que o SOpt, mais algumas pequenas alterações, e partir para o beta.

Ainda não estamos nesse estado. Sei que não parece tão complicado, e *não devia* ser tão complicado. É por isso que estamos revendo o processo.

Atualmente não temos recursos administrativos suficientes para sustentar o SUpt, e provavelmente não teremos pelo menos até o fim de 2015. As coisas podem mudar, até lá, já que podemos descobrir pequenas coisas que fariam uma grande diferença se forem mudadas.

***O SOpt vai muito bem, mas ainda não é grande o suficiente para gerar outro site***

Para termos confiança na abertura de outro site, precisamos estar razoavelmente seguros de que:

- O SUpt precisaria ter um grupo de pelo menos 100 usuários extremamente ativos
- Ceder esse grupo de usuários ao SUpt não causaria impacto negativo no SOpt. Não queremos que a nossa fila de análise deixe de andar, por exemplo.
- Existe uma demanda externa forte pelo SUpt, que criaria uma comunidade grande em torno do site, assim como ocorreu com o SOpt.

***Por que fechar a proposta?***

Porque assim que uma proposta atinge 100% na Area 51, o interesse ao redor dela começa a cair 5-10% para cada semana de espera até que o site saia. As pessoas arrumam outros interesses, mudam de emprego, se ocupam com outras coisas. No final das contas, não podemos esperar que, depois de ficar parada tanto tempo, a proposta fosse manter o mesmo grupo de pessoas dedicadas à ela.

Nós sabíamos que queríamos ter sites internacionais, mas não fazíamos ideia de como a coisa ia andar. Hoje nós temos uma noção melhor do que é necessário e não queremos mais uma proposta murchando até lá.

***Nós queremos o SUpt***

O SUpt está numa posição de vantagem, por já possuir grande parte da localização pronta, herdada do SOpt. Isso significa que abrir outros sites em Português é mais fácil que o resto.

Mas não queremos abrir um site atrelado a uma proposta quase morta. Assim como não gostaríamos que pessoas continuassem a se dedicar a uma proposta, esperando algo que no momento não podemos fornecer. Teria sido desonesto **não** dizer que não é possível abrir o site agora. E deixado todos participando, enquanto sabíamos que o trabalho seria em vão.

Seria impossível fechar a proposta sem desapontar todos os envolvidos, e nós *definitivamente* não gostamos de desapontar os outros. Não estamos dizendo "não". Estamos dizendo "agora não". Essa decisão é baseada na experiência de lançarmos mais de 130 sites, diversos vindos da Area 51.

Não estamos rejeitando a ideia do SUpt, mas não podemos concretizá-la *agora*. Deviamos ter agido mais cedo, para que o desapontamento não fosse tão grande, e por isso peço desculpas.

Comment: Se vocês quisessem o SUPT eventualmente não fechariam a pergunta. Somente colocariam a pergunta sobre o assunto.

Comment: Just think that down voting here is pointless. He made his point, defended his reasons and arguments. We are all talking at the chat. Just let it be. :(

Comment: Então fecha lá a [proposta de língua portuguesa](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language), senão perderemos os usuários do StackOverflowPT que migrarem pro site - baseando-se nesse "argumento".

Comment: SOpt did well or not? Your post ignore that SOpt was active proposal for 2 years and passive for more 2 years. Did it well? SUpt can be better. For all I know it has better engagament. I'm not talking about just number, which is better too, I'm talking about qhat **I know** about the commiters. You don't know and you was taken a **decision based on FUD**. I will never forget this.

Comment: Why shut it down? bullshit

Comment: So instead of losing 5-10%, you seem to prefer to lose 85-90%? Wow, really smart!

Comment: @VictorStafusa é mesmo isso que eles preferem! É ninguém se lembrar mais do SUpt!

Comment: SOpt+SUpt tudo aqui no SOpt é o que eles querem. Faz toda a lógica do mundo se pensarem na pergunta bloqueada sobre listas. A insistência em manter perguntas de SUpt cá. Saber que queriam apagar a pergunta do on-topic e por fim o FECHAMENTO da proposta com este motivo apresentado, quando todos os commiters dizem que preferem aberta uns anos do que fechada para sempre.

Comment: A maioria dos experts do SOpt não estavam no commit da proposta. A SE, propositalmente ou por ingenuidade está ignorando o fato que no momento que ela divulgar que está criando este site vai chover usuário novo, vários experts surgirão, como ocorreu com o SOpt. Este é o principal motivo de eu não criar o BigOverflow ou o BigUser :)

Comment: Tim, after reading your answer, the post at area 51 and the chat, what really annoys and frustrates me is the fact that you guys know that the Portuguese speaking community does NOT have a place to discuss Super User related content. SOPT community does not allow this kind of content (Gabe knows that), and yet you keep insisting that we post that kind of stuff in SOPT.If this is right or not I don't know (If we allow SU we should also allow code golf, code review, server fault, etc?).

Comment: What I know is that you talk a lot about SUPT splitting users from SOPT, which I don't think it's a good reason, since we ALREADY split our attentions between SOPT and several other online forums where we can discuss the kind of content who would be discussed in SUPT (such as OS or development tools setup). You say that SUPT would require a lot of active users and strong external demand, well I guess now we are never going to find out the kind of support it would have from the community, since you know, you guys shut down the whole thing.

Comment: I can understand if you guys don't want the trouble of having another Portuguese speaking community (hosting, localization, community management and all that stuff), but what I think everyone is upset about is the lame excuses that are being made and that make no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Muito bem dito @ArthurdeAndrade

Comment: É, o ponto do @ArthurdeAndrade é muito importante e mata o argumento da divisão de atenção. De fato quem gosta de infra está carente e está gastando a energia com o que gosta em outro lugar, não no SOpt. É isto que eu vejo com várias pessoas que eu referenciei. Uma quantidade que se ainda não é suficiente para garantir os experts, ainda seria possível atingir um número suficiente se a proposta ficasse aberta. Eu achava que em nem em 2016 a SE abriria o site, como ela acha que apenas seria difícil ser em 2015, a proposta tinha que ficar aberta. Podia até exigir que la tivesse + q 200 commits.

Comment: Do you know that SOpt's analysis queue is empty almost all of the time right? It is very rare to see more than 2 posts waiting review in any queue.

Comment: And the most active user caps everyday? Hey, I need more places to get fun :D

Comment: É que o pessoal da SE não sabe que os navegadores de hoje tem abas, e que podemos ficar nos 2 sites ao mesmo tempo. Eles acham que precisa sair do SOpt pra entrar no SUpt.

Comment: Exato. E também é muito difícil ter mais de uma conta nos sites da rede exchange. Quase impossível. Eu até agora só consegui em uns 4 ou 5, mas vo continuar tentando mais. :P

Comment: Trazer o conteúdo que seria do SUpt para o SOpt é a mesma coisa de dizer: "Olha, nós temos um site legal sobre **PROGRAMAÇÃO**, que tal nós bombardeá-lo ele com conteúdo que pouco (ou nada) tem a ver com o conteúdo que existe lá a 1 ano e 4 meses praticamente."

Comment: @emanuelsn Ver http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2546/227

Comment: Meu inglês está meio ruim mas eu entendi bem, tenho que concordar com Tim. Certamente iria dividir o SOpt se fosse criado o SUpt, os programadores iriam parar de se interessar por programação e acabar até mudando de emprego. Imaginem os melhores programadores da comunidade abandonando a carreira pra se dedicar a outro assunto? Isso é inviável.

Comment: Penso que alguns estão se comportando de forma um pouco infantil. Acho que a resposta do Tim é clara e bem embasada. Mostra as razões, embora você precise imaginar o que está por traz do trabalho da empresa.

Comment: As a SUpt expert willing to help, I accept your apologies regarding the delay to shut-down the proposal! I'll be happy to contribute, as soon as SE feels that is able to handle this new web-site properly.