# Mathematics em Português

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, status-recusado

Recebi o convite no meu facebook da seguinte proposta de site, e vim compartilhar aqui no meta do SOpt:

## [Mathematics (in Portuguese)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/87874/mathematics-in-portuguese?referrer=QaJh6ygnE6DT0LJwwOEdPw2)

A proposta foi criada há algumas horas atrás e já está com 56 seguidores (edit: agora é 62, pois 3 se juntaram enquanto eu redigia isso e mais 3 enquanto eu revisava depois de postar).

Você também pode contribuir com a criação do novo site indicando novos usuários. Compartilhe o link nas redes sociais e seu blog. Convide seus amigos e parentes (que tenham interesse na área). Colegas de trabalho ou de escola (alunos e professores), clientes e outros conhecidos. Não se esqueça que qualquer pessoa pode ser um beneficiário deste novo site. Ele não é só para profissionais, também é para estudantes e pessoas com dúvidas em matemática. Se puder, ajude a pessoa que está indicando a completar todo o processo do cadastro (que é simples mas por estar em inglês algumas pessoas poderão se confundir).

## Como ajudar?

- Siga a nova proposta do **Mathemathics (in Portuguese)** (Clique em *Follow It!* e não esqueça de confirmar seu e-mail quando a mensagem for enviada, caso você seja novo na Area 51).
- Vote nas 5 perguntas que acha que deveriam fazer parte do novo site. Esta é a parte mais importante.
- Convide pessoas que você conhece para fazer o mesmo.

Para ajudar você deve criar perguntas exemplo. Precisamos de pelo menos 40, provavelmente mais. Precisamos de algumas dezenas com boa diversidade de tópicos mas não muitas dezenas. Não faz sentido ter perguntas muito parecidas que na verdade representam o mesmo tópico. Isto não ajuda a definir nada. Se você não consegue ser criativo para criar perguntas que exprimem um tópico novo considere se abster de criar uma pergunta. Nem todo mundo mundo precisa criar perguntas. Todo mundo que quiser contribuir precisa seguir a proposta e votar positivamente em 5 questões exemplos. Pode negativar quantas quiser. Mas só negative se tiver certeza que a pergunta é muito ruim. Prefira fechar se for pertinente.

Para quem não conhece o processo é bom atentar para que as perguntas exemplo devem ser pensadas para indicar quais tópicos devem ser aceitos. Ou seja, ter duas perguntas do mesmo tópico não ajuda muito a definição. Não que seja proibido. Em alguns casos uma alta incidência do mesmo tópico de pergunta também é um indicador mas pode estar prejudicando a visibilidade de outros tópicos também importantes.

<sup><sup>E vamos torcer para que o resultado seja melhor do que [o SUpt em português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2482/132).</sup></sup>

Comment: Essa será a 3ª proposta de site PT-BR fechada em pouco tempo.

Comment: @emanuelsn Qual foi a segunda?

Comment: Tivemos o SUpt e recentemente a do Arduíno ( http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/87631/arduino-brasil?referrer=ZFjNfNER8wvSbb9C1niOqg2 )

Comment: "Sou Lusófono e não desisto nunca". Vamos que uma hora a gente consegue criar outro site em Português.

Comment: @Math, empolgado com a possibilidade de ter seu site em Português?

Comment: @emanuelsn na verdade eu fiquei assustado com as questões da proposta, eu "achava" que sabia matemática :( estou me sentindo indigno do meu nome, acho que vou mudá-lo para "Algorithm", ou algo mais relacionado à programação, rs..

Comment: Kkkkk - se vc ainda quiser um nick legal, use Rombicosidodecaedro.

Comment: Mas vocês já sabem que vai ser fechada, para que insistem?

Comment: Já agora, reorganizem os votos nas perguntas. Tem uma com 17 e só precisa de 10 cada uma.

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu mesmo, acho que os matemáticos vão ter uma surpresa desagradável quando o Tim Post fechar a comunidade, e alguns poucos deles já sabem que isso é provável, embora a maioria nem sequer deve imaginar isso. Por outro lado, enquanto isso não acontecer eu apoio totalmente a proposta. E quem sabe, com essa nova proposta, a SE não comece a repensar a situação?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Não é uma questão de "repensar a situação". A gente continua trabalhando pra conseguir ter mais sites internacionais no futuro. **Esse é o objetivo**. Não é uma decisão arbitrária, que a gente pode reverter na hora que bem entendermos.

Comment: E por que é que a gente não consegue? Fiquei decepcionado com o fechamento da proposta.

Comment: Vinicius, também queria saber, e compartilho da decepção. A proposta cresceu muito rápido (menos que dois dias?). Senti falta de uma explicação mais detalhada para o fechamento.

Comment: Eu também gostaria de entender melhor quais são os recursos técnicos que faltam. Por exemplo, o Stack Exchange em português ainda não suporta símbolos matemáticos em LaTeX (plugin MathJax ou similar), ou algo assim?

Comment: O mínimo que se espera dos moderadores do Stack Exchange em português é um disclaimer no meta explicando em detalhes a razão por trás desse e de outros cancelamentos similares, e de por que  propostas como esta não poderão ser aceitas no futuro próximo (pelo que eu entendi), com um comunicado aos moderadores da Area 51, para evitar que esse tipo de coisa aconteça de novo, senão a hora que o SE em pt realmente tiver "recursos técnicos e de pessoal" para tocar propostas como a nossa, ninguém mais vai botar fé, mesmo que eles anunciem aos quatro ventos.

Comment: Eu já estou com mais algumas proposta, uma comunidade sobre Vinhos e outra sobre Cristianismo, esta em paralelo a duas que existe em Inglês, é muito difícil para quem não domina o idioma inglês fazer uma pergunta sobre Vinhos ou Religião.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

É, não surpreendentemente, a proposta já era:

[image: Já era]

Como ele disse em um comentário aqui em cima:

> Não é uma questão de "repensar a situação". A gente continua trabalhando pra conseguir ter mais sites internacionais no futuro. **Esse é o objetivo**. Não é uma decisão arbitrária, que a gente pode reverter na hora que bem entendermos.

---

Para quem tiver dúvidas do motivo pode ver a explicação:

[Super User em Português - Por que o projeto foi fechado?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2543/super-user-em-portugu%C3%AAs-por-que-o-projeto-foi-fechado)

Comment: Fiquei mais surpreso por não ter sido fechada pelo Tim Post.

Comment: Como se estava a espera, as preocupações de perder membros do SOpt eram apenas desculpas, visto que este site nada tem a ver com o SOpt.
Então o único problema é a falta de CM's em Português.

Comment: @JorgeB. Nós demos **2** motivos pro fechamento do SUpt, um deles foi exatamente esse. E nunca escondemos que ele pesou *bastante* na decisão. A interseção grande entre as duas comunidades *também* foi uma preocupação grande e válida. Não entendo a insistência em pensar que nós escondemos alguma coisa, ou estamos querendo enganar alguém. Mas sinta-se à vontade pra continuar procurando chifre em cabeça de galinha.

Comment: Eu não estou a procura de nada @Gabe. Só constatei um facto.

Comment: @JorgeB. Um "fato" que, demonstradamente e publicamente, não está correto. Claro que é direito seu manter opiniões que não condizem com o que já foi dito e explicado dezenas de vezes, mas não significa que eu tenho que parar de explicar.

Comment: @Gabe em pt-PT é facto que se diz e escreve.

Comment: @Gabe acho que o problema maior foi excluir uma proposta que já estava fechada.

Comment: @JorgeB. lembre-se que uma das respostas que a SE deu foi "queremos o *SUpt*, mas não agora". Então basta esperar alguns meses e criamos a proposta novamente, aproveitamos para fazer o mesmo com o *Mathematics*. **:D**

Comment: @re22 Não. Esse não foi o problema maior. Se a proposta não fosse excluída, a reclamação seria do mesmo tamanho... só que por ter sido fechada. O problema maior é que parte dos usuários se recusa a entender argumentos simples e diretos sobre como e porque nós tomamos essas decisões (inclusive de excluir a proposta).