# Não deveríamos aceitar perguntas sobre áreas relacionadas com programação também, desde que feitas em português?

Tags: debate

A comunidade do SOpt é considerada única por não haver "até o momento" *subdivisões* como outras comunidades semelhantes, diferentemente do que acontece com outras comunidades maiores cuja linguagem oficial é o inglês.

- Por exemplo, existe a comunidade *Network Enginnering*, onde podemos inserir perguntas relacionada a rede de computadores.
- Por exemplo, existe a comunidade *Software Enginnering*, onde podemos inserir perguntas sobre métodos ágeis ou User experience.
- Por exemplo, existe a comunidade *Information security*, onde podemos inserir perguntas sobre segurança da informação etc.

Já que a comunidade do SOpt não é grande o suficiente para poder ter essas subdivisões de comunidade igual como é feita "lá fora", porque devemos nos preocupar em fechar questões como fora do escopo se uma pergunta sobre rede de computadores por exemplo pode muito bem ser aproveitada por outros usuários e ser principalmente útil para alguem da comunidade?

O fato de sermos lusófonos não gera alguma exceção a respeito do escopo? Ou devemos seguir a risca as regras pré definidas?

Comment: Mas o debate é super válido. Inclusive já o tivemos diversas vezes aqui. Por enquanto vou me abster de participar.

Comment: Tentei achar outra palavra que se sirva nesse contexto, só me veio essa ^^, tens alguma sugestão?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2482/132 e https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3867/132

Comment: Pior do que uma pergunta fora de escopo, é uma resposta dada por quem não é da área, como acontece de vez em quando quando o escopo é 'violado' aqui. Esses dias mesmo, teve uma resposta sobre Let's Encrypt que ignora completamente a filosofia do certificado automático, entre outros equívocos, e mesmo assim recebeu uma dezena de votos positivos. Esse tipo de problema acontece quando o assunto foge da área do público que vota, e prejudica todos os futuros leitores. Perguntas sobre licenciamento de software também são um exemplo de confusão de escopo (é problema jurídico, e não de programação).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

É para não atrair o público errado. Conforme vai tendo perguntas sobre algo que não é o nosso foco terá gente que não é programador caindo aqui e o *off topic* vai ficando cada vez maior.

Tudo o que for relacionado a programação, mesmo que tangencialmente está ok, o que é coisa de suporte, de infraestrutura já é algo que é cuidado para outro tipo de profissional. Tanto que a maioria do conteúdo dos sites internacionais de tecnologia da rede é aceito aqui.

Sempre é possível debater, mas precisa ter um consenso na comunidade, precisa ter argumentos para aceitar algo novo mais positivos que os negativos.

Comment: O ideia seria pergunta aqui no meta antes de postar então?

Answer (score 4):

Nenhuma comunidade tem **sub-divisão** e o escopo esta relacionado ao assunto da comunidade e não necessariamente ao idioma, claro que a obrigatoriedade aqui é usar português, assim como existe as comunidades *pt.stackoverflow.com* e *stackoverflow.com* também existem

- [ja.stackoverflow.com](https://ja.stackoverflow.com)
- [ru.stackoverflow.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com)
- [es.stackoverflow.com](https://es.stackoverflow.com)

Nenhuma delas tem ligação com a outra, são no máximo comunidades primas (ou semelhantes).

A motivação de não existir *Information security* e *Network Enginnering* é porque não houve **"necessidade"**, por exemplo, existe o caso do site [*superuser.com* (clique aqui para ver)](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=superuser.com), muita gente achou que seria interessante, mas a Stack Overflow, empresa e CMs (ou seja lá quem for) aparentemente não poderia dar suporte para uma nova comunidade no idioma português.

Existem questões que talvez algo assim, como criar um site em português para cada site que existe na **rede Stack Exchange**, não ir adiante, que claro só a empresa pode afirmar certamente se o que vou dizer são realmente os problemas/dificuldades:

- Público/Quantidade
- Disponibilizar funcionários
- Custo de servidores

Sim, a SO tem funcionários e é uma empresa e cada site da rede provavelmente tem um CM que "cuida" (não sei afirmar como é isto)

---

### Curiosidades

- A rede SE tem 170 sites/comunidades
- Existem sites na rede que não falam de tecnologia (um exemplo é um site que fala sobre "cafés" - https://coffee.stackexchange.com)
- Alguns sites tem domínios próprios, como superuser.com e askubuntu.com
- Alguns sites da rede como askubuntu.com tem menus que ligam com sites de outra organização, como o citado askubuntu que tem menus que apontam para os sites da Ubuntu

Comment: De fato a expressão "sub divisão" ficou mal empregada nesse contexto, a expressão "comunidades primas" ficou bem melhor.

Comment: Mas e o fato de usarmos o pressuposto da comunidade ser única para abranger um pouco mais o escopo? isso é discutível ou é uma cláusula pétrea.