# Devemos aceitar perguntas do SUpt?

Tags: debate

Infelizmente a proposta do [**SUpt**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/84282/super-user-em-portugues) foi fechada e acho que a grande maioria daqui não concordou.

Depois de muita repercussão e conversas um dos motivos que o pessoal do SE deu para fechar é que criar o SUpt iria afastar/dividir o pessoal daqui do SOpt e, segundo eles, enfraqueceria o SOpt.

Uma 'solução' apresentada por eles seria aceitar aqui no SOpt algumas (não todas) das perguntas que seriam do SUpt. Por exemplo, algumas perguntas que poderiam ser aceitas aqui, segundo eles, seriam:

- *Por que pesquisar um termo no Google leva menos tempo que pesquisar um arquivo no computador?*
- *Como funciona a compactação de um arquivo zip?*
- *Como posso baixar arquivos da internet pelo prompt de comando do Windows similar ao wget?*

Vocês gostariam de ver essas perguntas aceitas aqui no SOpt?

Eu particularmente não. Na minha opinião iria ficar mais bagunçado do que já está ficando.

Comment: Concordo com a tua opinião.

Comment: Na verdade é uma pergunta que já sabemos a resposta. Duvido alguém concordar com isso... mas, vai que....

Comment: Logo a ver se repondo a sua questão para que possas marcar como certa :P

Comment: Porque uma pessoa fechou a proposta? não seria necessário mais opiniões?

Comment: @MeuChapeu acompanhe aqui para ver os motivos: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2543/14674

Answer (score 10):

## Bagunça?

O site vai ficar tão bagunçado *quanto nós deixarmos*. Porém não consigo ver como exatamente uma pequena mudança no escopo vai prejudicar tanto a organização do site.

Por exemplo, eu conheço várias linguagens, mas nunca toquei em R, Lua ou Asp.NET. Cada profissional aqui tem uma área de conhecimento, domínio de N linguagens diferentes. Já convivemos com uma grade pluralidade de tecnologias. E é mais fácil todos esses profissionais terem um mínimo de conhecimento sobre sistemas operacionais, linha de comando, arquiteturas distribuídas, etc. do que sobre distintas plataformas de desenvolvimento, pois é algo que todos temos que lidar em algum momento.

Meu ponto é a "bagunça" não está diretamente relacionada ao escopo. Se há bagunça, e precisaríamos aqui definir no que ela consiste, é por outra razão.

Desde que os especialistas em cada tecnologia julguem corretamente e façam a triagem entre as perguntas boas e ruins, o site vai continuar com qualidade e até melhorar.

## Até onde poderíamos ir?

Shell Script, por exemplo, é como qualquer linguagem de programação. Comandos usados em terminais e prompts não são tão diferentes de uma linguagem em um ambiente interativo como Ruby ou Python.

E sobre certas perguntas como a primeira citada?

> Por que pesquisar um termo no Google leva menos tempo que pesquisar um arquivo no computador?

Isso tem tudo a ver com programação!!! Desde quando técnicas de *map-reduce* estão fora de escopo aqui?!

Decidir sobre on/off-topic em casos limítrofes depende muito da sua interpretação e conhecimento sobre o assunto, assim de como você enxerga o site.

## Qual é a sua filosofia sobre o SOpt?

Muito do que está em jogo nesta discussão está relacionado à forma como cada um entende o que é o SOpt e a expectativa com relação ao site.

Não me sinto à altura e nem acho proveitoso tentar definir de forma absoluta todas essas questões, mas eu por exemplo, vejo o site como um lugar onde posso fazer duas coisas ao mesmo tempo:

- Tornar-me um profissional melhor tendo contato com outros bons profissionais
- Ajudar outros profissionais, aprendendo no processo

Claro que quero também um site bonito e organizado, do qual possa me orgulhar de participar, mas não é minha prioridade transformá-lo numa *enciclopédia britânica da programação*, que só aceita perguntas excelentes que só profissionais muito experientes possam entender.

## Qual o seu objetivo aqui?

Ouvi alguém comentar ontem que estamos virando um tipo de *help desk*. Não é a primeira vez que ouço algo parecido. Há certo tempo um colega e excelente profissional recusou uma promoção para a equipe de P&D da empresa porque ele não gostaria de *dar suporte para outros programadores*, ou seja, ajudar desenvolvedores de produtos específicos com problemas que eles não conseguiam ou podiam resolver. Achei uma besteira, mas não julgo. Cada pessoa tem seu perfil.

Analogamente, talvez você está aqui somente para as perguntas épicas e super interessantes, relacionadas com o que você gosta muita. Mas em nenhum aspecto da vida humana é possível viver continuamente em estado de êxtase. É muito bom ter grandes perguntas de vez em quando, mas um site sadio deve saber conviver com perguntas rotineiras e medianas, tratando devidamente das ruins.

Do meu ponto de vista, ajudar as pessoas em dúvidas pontuais que elas enfrentam é um objetivo muito mais excelente para o SOpt por um simples motivo: *é disso que as pessoas vão se lembrar no futuro*, isto é, como elas conseguiram ajuda de um desconhecido especialista do SOpt para resolver um problema que para elas seria muito difícil ou até impossível. Creio nisto mesmo quando não agradecem ou esquecem de marcar a resposta como certa.

A reputação do site depende disso. Somos uma comunidade aberta a todos os desenvolvedores  em qualquer nível de maturidade e disposta a ajudar, ou uma panelinha que só deixa passar perguntas "perfeitas"?

Com certeza você já ouviu piadas do tipo *quando o SO sai do ar as empresas de TI param* ou então *usamos a metodologia de desenvolvimento baseado em Stack Overflow". Veja, a relevância do site é baseada em ajudar as pessoas a resolverem seus problemas e não em criar perguntas e respostas minuciosamente trabalhadas para serem tecnicamente perfeitas, obras-prima da tecnologia.

## Onde eu quero chegar?

Minha opinião é que não precisamos incentivar nem desincentivar perguntas que seriam do escopo do SUpt. Porém, ao invés de fechar automaticamente qualquer pergunta sobre linux e afins, devemos julgar caso a caso. Não vejo problema algum em futuramente migrarmos algumas para o SUpt.

Só um [exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987926/how-do-i-grep-recursively), eu *gostaria* de ver aqui perguntas sobre como usar o comando `grep` no linux, pois é algo super útil quando estou programando, seja via linha de comando ou chamando de dentro de uma linguagem de programação, mas sempre que vou usar esqueço algum detalhe de como o comando funciona.

Comment: concordo com quase tudo, mas quando se abre o escopo demasiado, vão aparecer muitas perguntas "como eu apago um ficheiro em linux?" e por ai fora. Parece-me que esse exemplo que deste do `grep` é uma exceção e não a regra. Ora a exceção devera fazer parte do escopo do site? Deixaria de ser exceção assim. Assim sendo, as perguntas de linux passariam a fazer parte do escopo. Depois por ai adiante até sermos SUpt+SOpt num só.

Comment: @JorgeB. Gostei do jeito que você colocou o assunto. Não creio que devamos fazer SUpt+SOpt, mas abraçar as exceções que sejam uma intersecção razoável entre os sites. Lembrando que esta é minha opinião.

Comment: Nesse caso a resposta continua a ser: Não, não aceitamos exceto algumas exceções.

Comment: Duvido muito que uma pergunta sobre grep fosse fechada aqui.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Exato, mas se levarmos estritamente ao pé-da-letra o escopo do SOpt vs SUpt, ela deveria ser fechada.

Comment: Nunca foi problema isso. É um argumento que me parece vazio, portanto usado para defender a tese de que aqui tem muita regra. Toda hora estamos abrindo exceção pra mil coisas e levando o assunto pro Meta, está se discutindo um problema que não existe. E se _pontualmente_ ele se manifesta, deve ser tratado pontualmente.

Comment: "Decidir sobre on/off-topic em casos limítrofes depende muito da sua interpretação e conhecimento sobre o assunto, assim de como você enxerga o site.", não, eu diria que depende do contexto da pergunta.

Comment: @Patrick Isso ***também***. Quem acompanha os casos de perto sabe que os usuários tem pontos de vista muito diferentes, independente do contexto.

Answer (score 3):

A resposta é óbvia: Sim. E não.

O escopo apresentado na proposta do SUpt era muito, muito amplo. Muito mais amplo que o escopo do SUen, por exemplo. Então o termos "perguntas do SUpt" pode significar qualquer coisa, desde *"Pra que serve o scroll lock"* (que, a titulo de curiosidade, ficou aberta por [quase 6 anos no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/142076/9835)) até *"Por que o Google é mais rápido que no meu computador"*, passando por "molhei meu teclado" e "o que são váriaveis de sistema"...

Dessa forma, o termo "perguntas do SUpt" significa, basicamente, qualquer coisa. A própria definição dele - ["interessados em hardware e software"](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/84282/) - é vaga e muito mais abrangente do que o SOpt, por exemplo.

Qualquer um que passar pela lista de perguntas sugeridas na proposta é capaz de encontrar pelo menos uma que poderia ser aceita no site, mas provavelmente mais de uma. Eu fiz o exercício, encontrei meu número. Mais pessoas fizeram a mesma coisa, e encontraram *outros resultados*, diferentes entre si e diferentes dos meus.

É óbvio, então, que cada um de nós tem uma ideia interna do que o SOpt deve ou não ser, e não existe uníssono. Pode haver um consenso maior sobre algumas perguntas. Eu e o Victor, [por exemplo](https://meta.superuser.com/a/9190/246698), concordamos que *"Porque PNG é um formato melhor que JPG?"* é uma boa pergunta para o site. Você pode discordar, mas isso não torna a pergunta imediata, e irremediavelmente, off-topic.

Além disso, algumas perguntas serem aceitas no site, mesmo que você discorde veementemente, não cria "uma bagunça". Não tem porque pensar isso. É só uma pergunta que alguém achou interessante, e outras pessoas também.

Em resumo. Sim, as perguntas do SUpt serão aceitas. E não, elas não serão aceitas.
Vai depender muito de *qual* pergunta estamos falando, e do que a comunidade como um todo pensa a respeito delas.

Comment: Serão aceitas se nós aceitarmos!

Comment: @JorgeB. Isso! Todos nós! Esse é o espírito!

Comment: E se por ventura, alguma dia, lá no futuro for criado o SUpt e tivermos aqui perguntas no escopo do SUpt, essas perguntas seriam migradas? Não iria confundir o usuário ou deixá-lo na dúvida de qual dos dois usar?

Comment: @Earendul é uma boa pergunta. Abrir o SUpt não significa, *necessariamente*, uma alteração no nosso escopo. Existem assuntos mais que suficientes que seriam cabíveis no SUpt e que não são permitidos aqui. A migração de algumas perguntas dependeria justamente da decisão de restringir o escopo do SOpt assim que o SUpt existir. Mas ainda é muito, muito, cedo pra tentar tomar essa decisão.

Comment: Não sei não... A ideia de "Sim, as perguntas do SUpt serão aceitas. E não, elas não serão aceitas." parece criar uma desordem e soa algo do tipo: "Deixe rolar e vamos ver o que acontece...". Creio que alguns usuários podem visualizar essa resposta do tipo: "Ah! Legal! Vou fazer algumas perguntas de Linux!" (Por exemplo)

Comment: @biio O que você sugere? Uma votação agora pra decidir a validade de cada uma das perguntas da proposta? E as perguntas fora da proposta? E as que não foram feitas? Qualquer site funciona julgando caso a caso. Você pode interpretar isso como "deixa rolar", mas no final das contas esse é um princípio básico do desenvolvimento das comunidades aqui. Não lide com problemas que você não tem.

Comment: É que, desde o começo, as ["regras" das perguntas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic) (que foram definidas pela própria comunidade) era justamente para evitar este tipo de problema, não era? O que eu sugiro é que enquadre também estes assuntos para diferenciar o SUpt (Que não existe) do SOpt e deixar a comunidade decidir, antes que vire um caos de pessoas dando UP vote e Down vote sem um argumento que não seja subjetivo.

Comment: @biio De novo, o princípio é não lidar com problemas que não existem. Essa pergunta diz, por exemplo, que são permitidas [perguntas de ERP](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/498/12), mas as [2 perguntas com a tag ERP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erp) foram fechadas (uma como off-topic). Também foi votada a [aceitação de code golf](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1027/12), mas as poucas perguntas que tivemos foram fechadas. O problema de se ter tanta regra, tão cedo, é que no final das contas, ninguém se lembra de aplicá-las.

Comment: Entendo. Então a funcionalidade real dos assuntos que devem ser tratados é apenas uma orientação do que como uma regra? Bom, então devo ter uma outra visão quando eu achar que uma pergunta deve ser fechada, independente se for on-topic ou não.

Comment: @biio Isso. Se um dia você vir uma pergunta e não tiver certeza se ela deve ou não estar no site, a melhor coisa a fazer é trazer pro Meta. Se já houver uma decisão sobre o assunto, alguém vai indicá-la. Se não houver, tomaremos uma, todos juntos.

Comment: O problema agora é que a proposta era muito ampla? **'-'**

Comment: @renan Claro. Esse sempre foi *um* dos problemas, mas não foi por isso que ela foi fechada, como todos nós sabemos.

Comment: Entendo! Agora ficou muito mais claro! Rsrs

Comment: @Gabe Se nós não tivessemos tantas regras logo no começo, esse site teria um escopo mal-definido e estaríamos discutindo por meses o que é ou não on-topic, tendo muito mais atrito durante esse processo.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Tem certeza? Nós estamos discutindo o que é `on-topic` há meses (desde a abertura do site). O SOen vem discutindo há 6 anos. Nossa página de `on-topic` na Central de Ajuda só foi mudada uma vez, e o site continua firme e forte. Além disso, diversos pontos daquela pergunta ou nunca foram postos em prática, ou foram tratados diferente do que ficou decidido lá.

Comment: @VictorStafusa e Gabe: aquela lista de perguntas on/off **não é uma lista de regras**. Talvez dê pra considerar "pré-regras". O objetivo daquilo é ajudar a gente mesmo a entender e definir o que é aceito. Dali devem ser derivadas umas poucas regras, todas bem claras, que sejam fáceis de entender até para usuários novos. Infelizmente não chegamos nesse ponto. Toda vez que discutimos isso, não saímos do lugar. De um lado a SE invalida completamente aquela lista, e uma parte a comunidade fica somente empenhada em defender a lista, por sentir sua autonomia ceifada. Resultado: o debate não avança.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu não devia nem mexer mais com esse assunto, pq depois de mais de ano, é causa perdida. Mas lá vai: "De um lado a SE invalida completamente aquela lista, e uma parte a comunidade fica somente empenhada em defender a lista, por sentir sua autonomia ceifada" - Se a SE invalida a lista, que publique as regras oficiais e pronto. Se não tem regra, não precisa das ferramentas de moderação. Se é a comunidade que decide, entao não tem como invalidar.

Comment: 2o ponto "parte da comunidade sente sua autonomia ceifada". Esse é o discurso que me enjoa há mais de ano. O problema não é esse e nunca foi. O problema é a zona que vem em seguida disso. Eu mesmo nao tou nem ai com a minha autonomia, e aposto que o resto do pessoal preocupado com organização não é "vista curta" como se rotula o tempo todo. Qualquer pessoa de bom senso pensa nas regras como meio de atingir um objetivo, e não pra dizer que manda. O problema é que geralmente quem tem poder acha que tem a visão também, e quase sempre isso tem se mostrado um engano (em diversas esferas).

Comment: @Bacco Concordo com você sobre a finalidade das regras, e todo meu esforço aqui tem sido para procurar um caminho pelo qual elas sejam definidas com um mínimo de consenso (claro que nunca haverá unanimidade em nada). Quando eu falei da autonomia ceifada, não foi uma queixa. É uma parte do que eu vejo ser dito *ad nauseam* nas discussões, mas que só tem servido para criar impasses, e não para resolver os problemas que de fato temos.

Comment: @bfavaretto se tem alguem que eu imagino que consegue entender isso é você, pelo extensivo e constante trabalho no site, desde que assumiu o diamante. Por isso achei bom me manifestar, pois eu acho que você consegue ir bém além desse argumento (que já foi usado de outras formas menos nobres aqui, em outros momentos).

Comment: Sim e não não parece óbvio ;)