# Por quê muitas perguntas sobre Excel (MSOffice) estão fechadas como fora de escopo?

Tags: debate, suporte

No início da semana o sistema do site trouxe para a home alguns tópicos antigos, de 2014, sobre Excel com dúvidas de uso do VBA.

Fiquei curioso e li algumas. Achei a maioria legítimo e dentro do escopo.

Aqui um exemplo: [Excel Como fazer para descobrir o endereço da celula atual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35518)

O VBA é uma linguagem de programação. O site SO-pt é específico para assuntos de programação.

Então fica a pergunta, por quê todos ou a maioria desses tópicos de Excel, principalmente os mais antigos de 2014, estão fechados como fora de escopo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No começo a ideia era que isso seria sempre considerado como coisa de usuário. Foi mudando a interpretação. De fato há uma certa [cisão na comunidade se deve aceitar esse tipo de pergunta ou não](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1436/101). Embora a prática tem mostrado que não está tendo problema.

Hoje parece mais aceito. Não sei se é o caso de reabrir as mais antigas, a não ser que alguém vá responder. Abrir e deixar morta lá não ajuda nada.

Por outro lado como parece que vai sair o [SUpt](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2482/101), ainda sem prazo, [precisaríamos ver se ainda deve aceitar ou não ou deixar para o SUpt](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2546/101). Acho que pode continuar aceitando e depois decidimos se deve migrar essas ou pode ficar aqui (não parece fazer mal). Só não sei se vale ficar abrindo o que talvez nem fique aqui, a não ser que seja respondida.

Comment: blz! Foi o que imaginei. Sobre a pergunta específica eu pedi para reabrir pois sei como responder.

Comment: @DanielOmine Tá feito.

Comment: Não tem como saber se as perguntas vão ser respondidas, a não ser que sejam reabertas.