# Área 51 - O que é necessário para uma proposta entrar em beta teste?

Tags: suporte, area51

Existe propostas na Área 51 que ficam por muitos meses nas fases de definição e compromisso. Quais são os indicadores dessas fases?

O que é necessário para uma proposta entrar em beta teste?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As informações podem ser lidas na [FAQ do site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).

Pode-se acompanhar a evolução da proposta na própria página dela. Tem indicadores dizendo o que falta para ela passar pra próxima fase.

[image: Definition][image: Commit]

Tem uma [pergunta no Metão sobre o cálculo exato](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53650/140010). Não vou entrar em detalhes porque é tem as informações em inglês e para usar o Area51 é preciso saber inglês, até porque [tentativas de propor sites em outras línguas serão abortadas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2482/101).