# Por que as perguntas do stackoverflow-pt não são fechadas por "baseada em opinião" tão facilmente

Tags: debate, perguntas-fechadas

Notei que muitas perguntas no stackoverflow português são do tipo:

- Para que serve a estrutura x ou y no c# ou php
- Qual a diferença de x e y?
- Melhor forma de fazer tal coisa

Muitas dessas perguntas não são problemas em si, são mais curiosidades, conceitos disponíveis na internet ou debates mesmo. [Essa questão é uma curiosidade de meta por exemplo]

**Exemplos**

- [Qual é a diferença entre dado e informação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/147467/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-dado-e-informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)
- [Qual é a diferença, na prática, entre “” e string.Empty?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151120/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-na-pr%C3%A1tica-entre-e-string-empty)
- [O que é normalização de banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151323/o-que-%C3%A9-normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-banco-de-dados)
- [Como funciona o "new" e o "virtual" no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151243/como-funciona-o-new-e-o-virtual-no-c)

Não que nenhuma não seja fechada, já vi várias questões assim fechadas, mas parece que a moderação aqui é bem menos rígida que no stackoverflow em inglês.

Isso seria devido não ter uma ramificação do "programmers", ou "code review" em português, sendo assim o pessoal não tem muito onde perguntar em português? Já foi cogitado se tem demanda para outro site do stackexchange em português para isso por exemplo?

Comment: Perguntas baseadas apenas em opinões geram debates/discussões interminavéis ou não produtivas e lembre-se o sopt não é um fórum. Sobre outros sites em português a resposta curta é, atualmente (isso pode mudar) não existe possibilidade, mais detalhes em [Outros sites da rede StackExchange não poderiam ter a versão em português?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4994/91)

Comment: Imaginei que não havia possibilidade mesmo. Talvez seja por isso que as perguntas baseadas em opiniões ou que são conceituais acabam passando de vez em quando, se eu não estiver errado, claro

Comment: @rray acho que ele disse "não fechadas", ou seja seria o contrário. Murilo quase todas opinativas eu vi serem fechadas, por favor forneça exemplos, de repente você interpretou como opinativa, mas não é. Se der alguns exemplos poderemos determinar e lhe orientar.

Comment: Nenhuma dessas perguntas é opinativa!

Comment: Certo! Mas aqui é o local correto para elas? Sabendo poderei um dia perguntar algo do tipo. Elas me parecem muito "wiki", principalmente as duas últimas

Comment: Talvez eu devo reformular a questão. Esses exemplos não são erros ou utilização incorreta de recursos. São pedidos de explicações, conceitos e esclarecimentos. Quero saber se isso pode. Obrigado.

Comment: Eu não tenho nada contra perguntas conceituais, pelo contrário. Que eu saiba, nem o SO em inglês tem. Pra mim a mais controversa dessa sua lista é a primeira (do dado/informação), porque envolve uma questão de ponto de vista (epistemológico, ou seja, os termos são usados em várias ciências e teorias). Tem até resposta com tablatura :). Ainda assim eu acho que a pergunta rendeu bons resultados.

Comment: Obrigado por adicionar os links, então Murilo ao meu ver as perguntas nada tem haver com opiniões, são duvidas sobre as linguagens e a primeira "diferença entre dados e informação" é uma pergunta de [tag:terminologia], o que é aceito pois é um tipo de duvida sobre os termos usados na área da programação. Ou como disse o bfavaretto e o bigown, são perguntas sobre conceitos. Nenhuma delas vai formar nada muito opiniativo, a não ser que AP queira induzir a isto, tipo uma resposta completa + um adicional de uma opinião dele. Todavia desde que tenha a resposta concreta primeiro é valido ;)

Comment: Essas que citou não são baseadas em opinião. Mas uma delas é fora de escopo. Essa do banco de dados é fora de escopo mas, por vezes, questões assim são "aprovadas/toleradas". Não sei dizer ao certo o motivo, mas há uma certa tolerância em permitir determinados conteúdos fora de escopo ou mesmo baseado em opinião. Se aplicassássemos a regra ao pé da letra, não deveríamos então permitir nada sobre `htaccess` ou `apache`, por exemplo. Mas é um assunto muito relacionado a desenvolvimento de websites, php, etc, então toleramos esse tema, tal como diversos outros. Pelo menos eu interpreto assim.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Somos o único site em Português

Pode-se dizer que aceitamos essas perguntas aqui porque não temos ramificações em Português. Nem faria sentido ramificá-lo já que somos pequenos.

## Ramificações

Pra falar bem a verdade eu acho que nem era para ter no SO. As perguntas nesses sites não causavam problemas de fato no SO. Tanto que na prática elas continuam sendo feitas nele. Tem mais perguntas do tipo "programmers" dentro do SO do que no Programmers.SE. Se fosse feita uma fusão dos sites muitas teriam que ser fechadas como duplicatas. Eu acho que o Programmers nem deveria existir. E já fui moderador lá. Acho que ele traz mais desvantagens que vantagens. Alguma coisa me diz que se fosse hoje ele não seria criado.

Não é segredo pra ninguém que acompanha o site que não gosto de alguns novos rumos da SE, mas acho que outros são bem adequados, entre eles o foco no desenvolvedor. E não precisa de um monte de site para isso.

Algumas pessoas criticam fragmentação. Eu também não gosto. É preciso entender quando temos um público diferente e um assunto diferente. Um site novo deve atender um público diferente e não assunto diferente. O público do SO e do Programmers é o mesmo.

Já [tentamos criar o SUpt](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2482/101), mas foi rejeitado. Esse seria o caso de ser separado porque o público é outro.

**Qual o ganho de separar essas perguntas?** Quem deseja precisa justificar isso. Precisa haver um ganho. Eu acho que só há perda aqui, mais que no SO. Não acho que haveria ganho nem que tivéssemos milhares de perguntas novas por dia.

## Perguntas baseadas em opinião

Note que [perguntas baseadas em opinião são proibidas em toda a rede](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/486/101). Então criar um novo site não resolve isso. Note também que muitas pessoas acham que perguntas subjetivas são proibidas. Isso não é verdade. Boas perguntas subjetivas são aceitam em todos sites da rede. Tem até critério para avaliar se a pergunta é boa ou não nesse aspecto. Eu sei até que algumas perguntas foram fechadas equivocadamente porque as pessoas não entendem isso. Raras as perguntas que devem ser fechadas por esse motivo. Pelo menos as postadas aqui.

Nenhum dos exemplos citados são baseadas em opinião. Eu diria que sequer são subjetivas. Pelo menos não mais que qualquer pergunta que pede um algoritmo pode ser subjetiva. Pra falar bem a verdade tem pergunta aí mais objetiva que pedir um algoritmo.

No SO tem um monte de perguntas fechadas por esse motivo por erro. É muito fácil achar 5 pessoas que não entendem direito esse motivo e resolvem votar para fechar algo que é bom. E passa a mensagem errada.

## Perguntas conceituais

Algumas são conceituais, nem todas. Perguntas conceituais são boas. Na minha opinião, se bem feitas e bem respondidas, podem ser melhores que a maioria das perguntas "de código" que tem por aí.

Vou lembrar que desde o início estabelecemos que qualquer assunto ligado diretamente ao desenvolvimento de software (desde que não seja apenas relacionadas colateralmente) poderia ser perguntado aqui. Nós podemos estabelecer o que queremos. Inclusive perguntas relacionadas à ciência da computação pura são aceitas.

Há alguma discordância quanto a isso, mas me parece que o grosso da comunidade aceita bem essa postura.

## Perguntas de baixa qualidade

O que é mais polêmico é a aceitação de perguntas de baixa qualidade. Alguns aceitam baixa qualidade em exagero, outros são demasiadamente restritivos com a baixa qualidade. Nem todos concordam sobre o que é qualidade.

A regra geral é que perguntas de baixa qualidade não são aceitas. O difícil é calibrar isso.

## Moderação

Por último a moderação faz o que a comunidade quer dela, pelo menos deve ser assim. Eu pelo menos tento fazer desta forma. Chego fazer até coisas que não concordo.