# Onde contribuir com perguntas e respostas de matemática?

Tags: debate, duvida

No mundo ideal, já teríamos o sítio pt.math.stackexchange.com

Mas não temos.

Posso criar perguntas e respostas aqui no stackoverflow português e um dia, quando tivermos o site de matemática migrar para lá as perguntas e respostas?

Comment: Infelizmente, não é o caso. Se assim o fosse, a gente teria coisas equivalentes do superuser, mas não temos. Se o assunto matemático em questão for relevante a um problema de programação / computação, então ele tem residência (permanente) aqui. Vou buscar exemplos de questões sobre matemática e pô-las aqui como exemplo do que é no escopo

Comment: Talvez o da [capicua](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/239450/5878) e o de [sistemas lineares](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/315484/5878) são dois exemplos dessa proximidade entre matemática e computação.

Comment: [Calculo da ordem assintótica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/236960/64969), [definição de assíntota](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/268409/64969), [expressão regular de uma gramática específica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241285/64969), [moduns ponens x tollens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137204/64969), [felicidade numérica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/282773/64969), [exponenciação nos reais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/272357/64969), [distribuição não homogênea](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/147884/64969), [representação binária](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/248453/64969)

Comment: O [chat] também é um bom lugar para falar do assunto

Comment: Outro problema são os de Pesquisa Operacional ou Programação Linear, que são problemas de otimização. Mas possuem programação por trás para realizar a modelagem e resolução destes. [O que é a Pesquisa Operacional no contexto da Computação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/278044/75104). Só não sei quais tags utilizar para estas perguntas...

Answer (score 10):

Por uma série de inferências de quem está aqui há 5 anos, não teremos outros site em português, ou mesmo outra língua que não seja inglês, a não ser, com muita sorte outro Stack Overflow de alguma língua nova. Não é que seja 100% impossível acontecer, mas já tivemos [tentativas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2482/101) antes em algo que faça mais sentido e não deu muito certo. Mas você pode tentar no [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). As chances são mínimas, até porque mesmo o investimentos nos Stack Overflows internacionais foram reduzidos (e acho que faz até sentido, não estou criticando), e o foco passou ser o SO mesmo, que também faz sentido.

Respondendo ao perguntado, sou contra misturar assuntos assim, não faz sentido algum, nunca fez nem no SO quando iniciou em 2008. Eu aceito discutir a inclusão mais claramente do Server Fault ou até do Super User (embora não queira não), mas Math considero completamente fora de questão. Eu aceitaria incluir perguntas que hoje não são aceitas sobre desenvolvimento de software.

Até é possível ter algumas perguntas que são um pouco de matemática, mas que de alguma forma esteja envolvida na programação, não que o foco seja a matemática em si. Nos comentários foram colocados bons exemplos.

Viraria bagunça manter assuntos tão distintos assim. E secundariamente abriria a porta para outros conteúdos.

Outras pessoas podem discordar de mim. Não sou "dono do site".

Comment: Compreendo então que o SOpt não é o lugar para fazer perguntas de matemática gerais, mas é o lugar onde se pode fazer perguntas de matemática que estejam ligadas com programação e suas perguntas e respostas devem providenciar código. Compreendi bem?

Comment: Sim, basicamente isto, ou seja, a matemática é secundária no problema. Quanto mais avançado for essa matemática mais estamos falando de computação, o que é dentro do escopo. Mas tem um monte de pergunta aqui que a pessoa só não sabe calcular porcentagem, ou não sabe inverter o sinal de um número, ou outras coisas bem de 5a. série. De uma certa forma quase tudo o que respondemos é matemática, mas bem aplicada.

Comment: Se perceber, em muitas das perguntas citadas (para não dizer todas) a matemática (explícita) foi utilizada para resolver o problema e permitir uma solução mais simples computacionalmente. Talvez o ponto central seja a *matemática aplicada*.