# Matemática básica faz parte do escopo?

Tags: debate

Já tivemos alguns casos de perguntas de matemática básica disfarçadas

- [Dúvida sobre mod](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/375319)
- [Como calcular porcentagem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88177)

E provavelmente outras mais.

Já teve uma discussão anterior no Meta sobre perguntas de matemática:

- [Onde contribuir com perguntas e respostas de matemática?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7478)

Mas não tratava especificamente deste assunto. Então, a fim de definir uma convenção, devemos ou não votar para fechar como fora de escopo perguntas que apresentam um problema de matemática básica?

Comment: Eu acho que por um lado é ruim aceitar esse tipo de pergunta porque pode desandar e aí vamos acabar tendo um problema com o escopo. Por outro lado eu acharia bacana termos uma abrangência maior de escopo porque não temos outros sites em português. Entretanto, eu ainda acho que matemática básica (como estas dos exemplos) não deveria se encaixar no escopo, acho que deveria ser algo mais voltado pra computação mesmo.

Comment: @LINQ Pois é, se fosse algo como "Ah, sei que para fazer regra de 3 é assim, mas como faço para implementar isso em Python?" talvez até se encaixaria melhor no escopo, mas tem umas aí que é literalmente matemática básica, como a de resto da divisão citada. A de porcentagem até fiquei meio no muro, mas citei porque ela já entrou na conversa algumas vezes.

Comment: Eu vi a pergunta sobre mod e fiquei na dúvida de se encaixava ou não, porém como foi relacionado a implementação acredito que faça um certo sentido.

Comment: @AndréLins Eu não sei até que ponto está realmente relacionada a implementação de fato. É como se eu perguntasse "*Multipliquei um número positivo e um negativo e o resultado deu negativo, por quê?*" - independente da linguagem, é uma questão puramente matemática, mesmo que eu tenha obtido esse resultado em um programa. Acho que cada caso é um caso e é difícil ter uma linha de corte única, mas no caso da pergunta sobre mod, acho que está fora do escopo sim, pois se trata de apenas matemática, sem nenhuma relação com programação.

Comment: @AndréLins No caso ali não é implementação, é falta de entendimento mesmo. Seria de implementação se fossem números negativos, por exemplo, ou um caso de overflow. Lá simplemente o autor diz que sabe o que é o operador, mas não parece ser o caso, afinal ele usa o número maior à direita e acha o resultado estranho.

Comment: Entendo, por via das dúvidas não estou respondendo questões assim e deixando pra vocês avaliarem.

Comment: Acredito que perguntas como essa [da porcentagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88177/como-calcular-porcentagem), não devam ser consideradas como contidas no escopo do site.  O usuário sabe como utilizar as variáveis e falha no momento de organizar a estrutura do cálculo, por isso acredito que a questão não esteja relacionada à implementação de qualquer linguagem

Comment: Lembrando que o fato de estar em discussão não impede da comunidade já votar para fechar. CASO se chegue numa conclusão diferente (o que eu realmente espero que não aconteça), o post pode ser restaurado. A comunidade esperar para agir pelo fato de algo estar em discussão no meta não me parece boa idéia, pois corre-se o risco (diria que é o que quase sempre acontece) de não se chegar a nenhuma conclusão e o problema ficar indefinidamente no site.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss mas aí podemos pelo menos saber que o cara não vai poder ir pro espaço... :D Na verdade nem sei se dá pra implementar regra de 3 em Python sem estar falando puramente de matemática. Eu acho o assunto difícil de definir, até onde ficou na matemática pura e onde começa como fazer no código. Não vi maiores problemas até agora, fico em cima do muro.

Comment: @Maniero eu também não consegui me decidir, por isso resolvi abrir a discussão, principalmente para tentar diminuir os casos de algumas ficarem abertas e outras serem fechadas como fora do escopo.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, acredito que é possível aceitar questões de matemática básica como parte do escopo do site enquanto mantivermos um parâmetro objetivo: a sua **aplicação**, e nesse aspecto concordo com a linha de pensamento apresentada por você e pelo Maniero no tópico [Onde contribuir com perguntas e respostas sobre matemática?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7478/onde-contribuir-com-perguntas-e-respostas-de-matem%C3%A1tica). Muitas vezes, ao buscar por uma otimização de um algorítimo, buscamos a teoria matemática por trás dele e/ou alguma outra que possa nos auxiliar (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Acredito que possamos entrar em uma discussão mais aprofundada sobre como definir parâmetros objetivos para diferenciar questões **APENAS** matemáticas das questões computacionais que **INCLUEM** uma base matemática para suas respostas. Minha sugestão é que o autor deixe explícita a necessidade do entendimento matemático para a resolução/otimização de um problema computalcional, pois é algo que já é pregado no SOpt no que diz respeito a ser um Q&A de programação.